# How to automatically edit over 100k files on GCS using Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have over 100 thousand files on Google Cloud Storage that contain JSON objects and **I'd like to create a mirror maintaining the filesytem structure, but with some fields removed from the content of files.**

I tried to use Apache Beam on Google Cloud Dataflow, but it splits all files and I can't maintain the structure anymore. I'm using [`TextIO`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/0.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.html).

The structure I have is something like `reports/YYYY/MM/DD/<filename>`
But Dataflow outputs to `output_dir/records-*-of-*`.

**How can I make Dataflow not split the files and output them with the same directory and file structure?**

Alternatively, is there a better system to do this kind of edits on a large number of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly use `TextIO` for this, but Beam 2.2.0 will include a feature that will help you write this pipeline yourself.

If you can build a snapshot of Beam at HEAD, you can already use this feature. *Note: the API may change slightly between the time of writing this answer and the release of Beam 2.2.0*

- Use [`Match.filepatterns()`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/Match.java) to create a `PCollection<Metadata>` of files matching the filepattern
- Map the `PCollection<Metadata>` with a `ParDo` that does what you want to each file using [`FileSystems`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileSystems.java):

  - Use the `FileSystems.open()` API to read the input file and then standard Java utilities for working with `ReadableByteChannel`.
  - Use `FileSystems.create()` API to write the output file.

Note that `Match` is a very simple `PTransform` (that uses `FileSystems` under the hood) and another way you can use it in your project is by just copy-pasting (the necessary parts of) its code into your project, or studying its code and reimplementing something similar. This can be an option in case you're hesitant to update your Beam SDK version.

Comment: I took your suggestion, but I'm using 2.1, so I replaced `Match.filepatterns()` with an `ExpandFilePatternFn` function that uses `FileSystems.match(filepattern)` and outputs the matches.

Unfortunately Dataflow fuses that with the previous `Create.of(options.getInputPattern())` and the following `DoFn` that edits the files, killing the parallelism.

Do you have a suggestion for preventing the fusion, or do I really need 2.2?

Comment: Also, it seems that the ParDo that edits the files will block on I/O, since `processElement` only returns after the read, process and write is done, rather than leave it to the Runner do do the I/O. Is it possible to make `processElement` non-blocking so that the worker can process more in parallel?

Comment: Yes, you need to insert a fusion break. See https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#preventing-fusion